# PowerShell / REG DELETE: How to use registry paths including spaces within a loop?

Tags: powershell

I want to delete particular registry paths using a PowerShell script loop:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\test" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if((Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match "Matching Value including Spaces") {
        $regkey = """ + $_.PsPath + """
        reg delete $regkey /f
    }
}
```

But it does not find the registry path(s) as it is not correctly adding the quotation marks. I've also tried different variants with and without `+`.

How do I either add quotation marks into the variable itself or before and after the variable for usage with `REG DELETE`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `Remove-Item` instead of `REG DELETE`:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\test" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if((Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match "Matching Value including Spaces") {
        Remove-Item $_.PsPath -Recurse -Force -Verbose -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```